# Python's Regular Expression Source String Length

Tags: python, regex

In Python Regular Expressions,

```
re.compile("x"*50000)
```

gives me `OverflowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded`

but following one does not get any error, but it hits 100% CPU, and took 1 minute in my PC

```
>>> re.compile(".*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?"*50000)
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x03FB0020>
```

Is that normal?

Should I assume, `".*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?"*50000` is shorter than `"x"*50000`?

Tested on Python 2.6, Win32

**UPDATE 1**:

It Looks like `".*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?"*50000` could be reduce to `.*?`

So, how about this one?

```
re.compile(".*?x"*50000)
```

It does compile, and if that one also can reduce to `".*?x"`, it should match to string `"abcx"` or `"x"` alone, but it does not match.

So, Am I missing something?

**UPDATE 2**:

My Point is not to know max limit of regex source strings, I like to know some reasons/concepts of `"x"*50000` caught by overflow handler, but not on `".*?x"*50000`.

It does not make sense for me, thats why.

It is something missing on overflow checking or Its just fine or its really overflowing something?

Any Hints/Opinions will be appreciated.

Comment: No ".*?x"*5000 does not reduce down to ".*?x" - it reduces down to a regex with 5000 x's in, with ".*?" before each x. This is why it does not match "abcx" or "x" -  it will only match a string with 5000 x's.

Comment: It reminds me, that I hit once PHP's maximum length for regular expressions, when I tried to convert the ABNF for SVG paths into a regexp. So, IMHO, the answer would be good to know.

Comment: @Dave Kirby, Thanks, but its 50000 (50k). My original questions is `re.compile("x"*50000)` does not get compiled, but `re.compile(".*?x"*50000)` got compile.

Comment: Why do you need to know the maximum regex?  Write the regex you need.  `x{5000}` or `x{500000}` or whatever.  When you reach the limit, there you are.  What's the point of knowing where the limit is?  You don't need to know until the (unlikely) even that you write a REAL regex thats too long.  Not these degenerate cases that aren't sensible regexs in the first place.

Comment: @S.Lott, You're right, knowing the limit is no points at all, but, don't you think it can be vulnerable for Buffer Overflow when `"x"*50000` got caught by overflow handler, but `".*?x"*50000` does not, even `".*?x"*100000` does not.

Comment: Regular expression compiling buffer overflow is not a "vulnerability".  Regular expressions are a design-time feature.  You debug them yourself.  Once they work, the compiled form the regular expression *works*.  It doesn't spontaneously get bigger and have a buffer overflow.  There's no user input.  It may as well be statically compiled into your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that `".*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?.*?"*50000` can be reduced to `".*?"`, while `"x"*50000` has to generate 50000 nodes in the FSM (or a similar structure used by the regex engine).

**EDIT:** Ok, I was wrong. It's not that smart. The reason why `"x"*50000` fails, but `".*?x"*50000` doesn't is that there is a limit on size of one "code item". `"x"*50000` will generate one long item and `".*?x"*50000` will generate many small items. If you could split the string literal somehow without changing the meaning of the regex, it would work, but I can't think of a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks, but how about `re.compile(".*?x"*50000)`?

Comment: I don't really know about internals about the Python regex engine, so I'm not sure. The regex should match 50000 x's with any characters between them. I don't know what optimalizations does it do, but it's likely that it does something special about the regex. FYI, all of the regexes work on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for info about linux version, I just checked _sre.c -> _compile function, there is no specific code for windows, so it may be because of some size different like `wchar_t` and/or your python is compiled with `Unicode=UCS4`

Comment: `"x"*50000 will generate one long item and ".*?x"*50000 will generate many small items`, Thank you, that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

you want to match 50000 "x"s , correct??? if so, an alternative without regex

```
if "x"*50000 in mystring:
    print "found"
```

if you want to match 50000 "x"s using regex, you can use range

```
>>> pat=re.compile("x{50000}")
>>> pat.search(s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb8057a30>
```

on my system it will take in length of 65535 max

```
>>> pat=re.compile("x{65536}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 188, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 241, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 529, in compile
    groupindex, indexgroup
RuntimeError: invalid SRE code
>>> pat=re.compile("x{65535}")
>>>
```

I don't know if there are tweaks in Python we can use to increase that limit though.

Comment: Thanks for the update for the code, but `{65535}` is the repetation limit, thats a bit different with mine. `"x"*50000` and `"x{50000}` is different in my understanding.

Comment: "x"*50000 produces 50000 x's.. in a regex, if you put x{50000}, you are telling the regex engine to search for 50000 x's as well... Or am i missing something ? you should clearly state what you want to do in your question with examples...

Comment: @ghostdog74, you are right, I can use x{50000} if I want to match 50000 x. I am just wondering re.compile is safe or not and testing for vulnerablity. thats all.

Comment: well, as you can see, string length exceeding 65535 (for my system) crashes the regex engine and produce error. I would suggest checking your string according to your application specs before passing it to re.compile.