# Django says OverflowError at /admin/ while trying to access /admin/

Tags: regex, django, url, overflow, admin

I noticed this error while trying to access /admin/. Whenever /admin/model_name or /admin/ or /admin/* is accessed django says `OverflowError at /admin/` and `regular expression code size limit exceeded`. I did a little digging and came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998261/pythons-regular-expression-source-string-length). I have checked urls.py of app since regex are mostly used in urls. But all I have is a typical admin url, nothing complex.

```
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ....
]
```

#### Stack trace

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET
>   Request URL: http://domain/admin/
>
> Django Version: 1.9.8
>   Python Version: 2.7.6
>   Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',
>   'django.contrib.auth',
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>   'django.contrib.sessions',
>   'django.contrib.messages',
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>   'rest_framework',
>   'haystack',
>   'myapp.apps.core',
>   'myapp.apps.home',
>   'myapp.apps.accounts',
>   'myapp.apps.dashboard',
>   'myapp.apps.app1',
>   'myapp.apps.app3',
>   'myapp.apps.app5',
>   'myapp.apps.app6',
>   'myapp.apps.app7',
>   'myapp.apps.app8',
>   'myapp.apps.app9']
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>    149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>    147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
>    265.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>    149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
>     57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
>     244.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)>
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
>    57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)>
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
>    505.         app_list = self.get_app_list(request)>
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in get_app_list
>    488.         app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)>
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in _build_app_dict
>    473.                         current_app=self.name,
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
>     600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._revers>e_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
>
> File "/home/tuxbox/.virtualenvs/dekkho-qa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix>
>     488.                 if re.search('^%s%s' % (re.escape(_prefix), pattern), candidate_pat % candidate_subs, re.UNICODE):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py" in search>
>     142.     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py" in _compile>
>     242.         p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py" in compile
>    521.         groupindex, indexgroup
>
> Exception Type: OverflowError at /admin/
>   Exception Value: regular expression code size limit exceeded

We are using `django+apache`.

Any help is much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: do this bug happen in local environment when you run it with ./manage.py runserver?

Comment: No it happens when trying to run django app with apache.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by restarting apache2 with

`sudo service apache2 restart`.

Of course, I have inspected apache2 error log with 
`sudo tail-f /var/logs/apache2/error.log` 
But that gave me `same output as stack trace`. Aforementioned is a work around for this issue. I am not marking this question as solved since real issue have not been found yet.

Thanks.